# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):

Tags: django, django-csrf

I am making ajax call like below:

```
var data_dict = {'user':{{ user.id }}, 'bookId':that.id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"/issuebook",
        data:data_dict,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(response)
        {
        }
    });
```

urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.checkLogin,name='checklogin'),
url(r'^mylibrary/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<user_name>[\w\-]+)$',login_required(views.MyLibrary.as_view()),name='mylibrary'),
url(r'^centrallibrary/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<user_name>[\w\-]+)$',login_required(views.CentralLibrary.as_view()),name='centrallibrary'),
url(r'^issuebook$',login_required(views.IssueBookView.as_view()),name='issuebook'),
```

]

I am getting "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /issuebook" error on ajax call.

The csrf token in ajax call is getting rendered as:

```
var data_dict = {'user':{{ user.id }}, 'bookId':that.id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':'fSSdu8dJ4FO6FvDz8eU5ISzOewRYyGbC'};
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url:"/issuebook",
                        data:data_dict,
                        contentType: false,
                        success:function(response)
                        {
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You just passed the string `'{{ csrf_token }}'` as `csrfmiddlewaretoken`, and your ajax call can't match it with the relative one. Instead you can get the hash value of `csrf` token manually from your html in your call function.

Comment: Add the rendered HTML template in the question too.

Comment: @v1k45 i have added the rendered {{ csrf_token }} in the edited question. Apart from this I am just rendering few string values in the template which is working fine

Comment: @v1k45 also I am not using any forms in the template. This ajax call is done on button click event

Comment: Try setting the `X-CSRFToken` request header to `csrftoken`, in ajax request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is caused by `processData` and `contentType` options in your ajax function. Removing these two options will fix the issue.

**Explanation:**
The arguments must be sent to Django as urlencoded with Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Whereas, if you set `processData: false` it won't encode the POST parmaters and `contentType: false` will send ajax POST request as `text/plain`.

Comment: What if it's set to this?  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8. Will that work? I get the same error as above.

Comment: @Axwack No, it won't work. Django does't understand `application/json` POST request. Try sending the data as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you can't control the request, there's another way to accept `json` request. If you'd like to know, I'll post another comment.