# How do I send my updated data and save it using Bootstrap Modal in django?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use Boostrap Modal to pop up an edit form that should send the **thought** and its **id** to my views function using Ajax, **edit**, and save it. However, when I press the Save Changes button on my modal, nothing happens. Being very new to this, I can not figure out exactly where to go on the internet so it would be great for me if anyone here could direct me on what to read and what I'm doing wrong.

my html -

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Edit</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
          <form method = "POST" enctype= multipart/form-data id = "editt">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <textarea id = 'thought' style="resize:none" type = "text" placeholder = "{{ obj.thought }}." rows = "5" cols = "40" name = "thought" required></textarea><br>
      </div><br>

      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <a type = "button" data-catid = "{{ obj.id  }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submit" id = "upload-form-btn">Save changes</button></a>

          </form>
      </div>
      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
         $('.submit').click(function(event) {
            var id = $(this).parent().attr("data-catid");
            var thought = $("#thought").val();
            alert(id + "datas  "+thought)
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'edit',
                data: {
                    'thought': thought,
                    'id': id,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
                contentType: false, // add this to indicate 'multipart/form-data'
                success: function(response) {
                alert('Form Submitted');
                location.reload();
                },
                error: function(data) {
                //alert('Form submission failed');
                }
            });

            });

    </script>
```

my views.py's edit function:

```
   if request.method == "POST":
       thought = request.POST['thought']
       id = request.POST['id']
       thought_x = Thought.objects.get(pk = id)
       form = ThoughtForm(request.POST or None, instance = thought_x)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [ path('edit',views.edit, name = 'edit'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Models.py showing the model I am trying to update:

```
class Thought(models.Model):
    thought = models.CharField( max_length=300)
    done = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete =models.CASCADE, default = None)
```

Comment: You have many errors inside your jquery codes . Start with checking errors inside browsers console .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I did not realize the mistakes before. I will be fixing them and updating the code here if it still does not work.

Comment: Your code is still not right .  I have made [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmv467y9/) use that jquery code and try again.

Comment: Also , as  you are using ajax you cannot redirect from your django code do that part inside success function of ajax .

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. I replaced my code with yours and now there's an alert message, but I keep getting an error saying "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /retro/edit".Could you suggest on that? I changed the code according to your directions.

Comment: Hi, change `'{{ csrf_token }}'` to `$("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()` .

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Changed the code but I am still facing the same error.

Comment: print and see what does `$("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()` has i.e : `alert($("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val())` .

Comment: this is being printed as a csrf value: wd5e2IQUHbU5MJorJj02LGeHnVvjYntZjvk4ZON8zGnl06g0gFijHYCgSh2TH2kx

Comment: see if this value matches with `{% csrf_token %}` inside form modal . Just open browser element tab and scroll down to that element and verify same.

Comment: Yes, they match. What does it mean?

Comment: it should work then if they match .. i am not sure what might be problem here .

Comment: Oh, thank you! I will try to solve it, and ask here again if I face new questions! Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @Swati, I could get it to work. I had to remove ```contentType: false ```. I got the solution from this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36292539. 
Thanks a lot for all your help! I just finished my first project.

Comment: **Explanation**(Copied from the link above): The arguments must be sent to Django as urlencoded with Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Whereas, if you set processData: false it won't encode the POST parmaters and contentType: false will send ajax POST request as text/plain.